# How to register a concrete class's string dependency in ASP.NET Core dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How does one register a concrete class's dependency in regular ASP.NET Core dependency injection?  For example, if I have a FooController whose constructor takes a string, I thought I could do this in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<FooController>(_ => new FooController("any string"))
```

However, that doesn't work; I get "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate"  Isn't there a way to inject string parameters into concrete controllers?

`

Comment: What does this string represent? A connection string? An API key? Something else? A naked string is a terrible thing to inject. Normally controllers would depend on something by type: but a string is just too generic to go injecting into things. You might have other strings you'd want injected into other classes. How would you know which one goes to which class? You could do named registration, but that's a mess. You'd be far better off creating a type to encapsulate the string, such as MyDatabaseSettings and have the string be a property of that type. Then register MyDatabaseSettings with DI

Comment: In this case it is a name of a named HttpClient that an underlying library uses.  So I will create a IHttpClientNameProvider to return the string.  That doesn't strike me as better.